# Generic and non-generic method with similar body

Tags: c#, generics, optimization

I have a method called `ExecuteAsyncServiceRequest` with an overload, you'll notice that the body of the both methods are similar. I find myself wondering is there a more concise way of writing these methods? Specifically, to not have to repeat myself in the method body.

Thanks in advance!

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes an async service request which returns a response of type TResponse
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The service request to execute</param>
    /// <param name="success">Callback when the service request is successful</param>
    /// <param name="failure">Callback when the service request fails</param>
    /// <typeparam name="TResponse">Type of the expected ServiceResult returned from the async request</typeparam>
    protected async void ExecuteAsyncServiceRequest<TResponse>(Func<Task<ServiceResult<TResponse>>> execute,
                                                            Action<TResponse> success,
                                                            Action<string> failure)
    {
        ServiceResult<TResponse> result = await execute();

        if (result.ResultCode == ServiceResult.ServiceResultCode.Failed)
            failure(result.FailureDetails);

        success(result.Response);    
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes an async service request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The service request to execute</param>
    /// <param name="success">Callback when the service request is successful</param>
    /// <param name="failure">Callback when the service request fails</param>       
    protected async void ExecuteAsyncServiceRequest(Func<Task<ServiceResult>> execute,
                                                    Action success,
                                                    Action <string> failure)
    {
        ServiceResult result = await execute();

        if (result.ResultCode == ServiceResult.ServiceResultCode.Failed)
            failure(result.FailureDetails);

        success();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a explanation of what you have tried, and what doesn't work.

Comment: @SneakyTactician The code works well, but I found myself asking the question "How would you optimize this? Can it be optimized?". Maybe the answer is simply "no"?

Comment: If ServiceResult and TResponse inherit from the same class or use the same interface, then you could generically combine the methods. If not, see Stephan's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Unfortunately, this is due to a limitation in the type system of .NET itself - specifically, that `void` is not a type.

Languages with more of a functional influence (as opposed to classical OOP) tend not to have the concept of `void`; instead, a special type (commonly called `unit`) exists that has a single value. Something like this:

```
public sealed class Unit {
  private Unit() { }
  public static Unit Instance { get; } = new Unit();
}
```

You can do something similar with your code, but it's up to you whether it's worth it or not:

```
protected async void ExecuteAsyncServiceRequest(Func<Task<ServiceResult>> execute,
                                                Action success,
                                                Action <string> failure) =>
    ExecuteAsyncServiceRequest(
        async () => new ServiceResult<Unit>(await execute(), Unit.Instance),
        _ => success(),
        failure);
```

This is assuming `ServiceResult<T>` can have a (possibly `internal`) constructor that takes `ServiceResult` as an argument and copies over all its properties except the actual "result" which is copied from the second constructor parameter.